# Adding description outside the plot with coloured text

Tags: matlab, plot, label, matlab-figure

I am working on a visualisation of my data and would like to add a description of a plot. The description will be added outside the plot. For that I have written:

```
plot(1:10)
text(2,8,'my text here ','Color','green','FontSize',14,'location','EastOutside')
```

But it doesn't work, I get the error:

> There is no location property on the Text class.

How can I fix this?

This is my desired output:

[image: pic]

Comment: I rolled back the edit, as the new question was asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59715170/multiline-annotation-problem-with-num2str)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `location` input pair you're giving to `text` are for the `legend`, not `text` objects...

The location is specified by the first two inputs (x/y), so if you don't use the `location` input you get this:

```
text( 2, 8, 'my text here ', 'Color', 'green', 'FontSize', 14 )
```

[image: plot with text]

If you want the text location to be independent of the axes, you should use an `annotation` instead, which gets its location from the *figure* rather than the *axes*.

```
annotation( 'textbox', 'String', 'my annotation', 'Color', 'green', ...
            'FontSize', 14, 'Units', 'normalized', 'EdgeColor', 'none', ...
            'Position', [0.8,0.5,0.2,0] )
```

Because I used `normalized` position here, the `Position` argument is a percentage of the figure window. To get the behaviour I suspect you're after, you'll have to reposition the axes too...

```
set( gca, 'Position', [0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.8] )
```

[image: plot with annotation]

Comment: How can i use `annotation` in case `Edit 1`? I would like to add text in more than one line with parameters I used

Comment: @user176070 that is a different question (multi-line text) to the one you asked (positional, coloured text). Which is important? What is the actual desired result? Please try and avoid scope creep, or mark an answer as accepted and write a new question.

Answer (score 0):

`text()` is the wy to go if you want an arbitrary description somewhere on your figure, but if your just want to place the legend outside, use the location Name-Value-pair in `legend(...,'Location,'northeastoutside')`. The example puts the legend on the top right next to your figure.