# Multiline annotation: problem with num2str

Tags: matlab, plot, text, annotations

I expect the text in the textbox to show up as:

```
Simulation parameters: 
Number of loops = 500
Number of subcarriers = 12
Number of frames = 5,
MT = 2, MR = 2               % or MR x MT = 2 x 2
```

I have code written as:

```matlab
txt = {'Simulation parameters: ','Number of loops = ',  num2str(loops_num),'Number of subcarriers = ',num2str(Nfft),,'Number of frames = ',num2str(K),'MT = ',num2str(MT),'MR = ',num2str(MR)};
text(4,0.5,txt,'FontSize',12)
```

And I got:

[image: results]

1) How to fix it? (`Number of subcarriers = 100`, etc need to be on one line)

2) How can I use `annotation` in such a case?

```
plot(1:10)
str = {'Simulation parameters: ','Number of loops = ',  num2str(loops_num),'Number of subcarriers = ',num2str(Nfft),'MT = ',num2str(MT),'MR = ',num2str(MR),'Number of frames = ',num2str(K)};
annotation( 'textbox', 'String',str, 'Color', 'black', ...
            'FontSize', 14, 'Units', 'normalized', 'EdgeColor', 'none', ...
            'Position', [0.8,0.5,0.2,0] )
set( gca, 'Position', [0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.8] )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is, you create a cell array of char arrays ("strings"), which is interpreted as separate lines when used in `annotation`. So, you have to concatenate those values, which you want to have to be merged to one line by using `[ ... ]`. See the following short example:

```matlab
plot(1:10);
str = { ...
  'Simulation parameters: ', ...
  ['Number of loops = ', num2str(500)], ...
  ['Number of subcarriers = ', num2str(12)], ...
  ['MT = ', num2str(2)], ...
  ['MR = ', num2str(2)], ...
  ['Number of frames = ', num2str(5)] ...
};
annotation('textbox', [0.3, 0.6, 0, 0], 'String', str, 'FitBoxToText', 'on');
```

The output (Octave 5.1.0; code also tested in MATLAB Online) looks like this:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!

---

**EDIT:** On the question, if the annotation could be moved outside the figure. It's possible, **BUT** incorporates manipulating the figure properties. That's the modified code:

```matlab
plot(1:10);
set(gca, 'Position', [0.1 0.1 0.6 0.8]);
str = { ...
  'Simulation parameters: ', ...
  ['Number of loops = ', num2str(500)], ...
  ['Number of subcarriers = ', num2str(12)], ...
  ['MT = ', num2str(2)], ...
  ['MR = ', num2str(2)], ...
  ['Number of frames = ', num2str(5)] ...
};
annotation('textbox', [0.75, 0.60, 0, 0], 'String', str, 'FitBoxToText', 'on');
```

That's the updated output:

[image: New output]

Comment: Note that the positional edit was already addressed in the OP's [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59681725/adding-description-outside-the-plot-with-coloured-text/59681896#59681896)

Comment: @user176070 You were told before (see Wolfie's comment on your earlier question linked by him) not to extend your questions in an inappropriate manner. Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab doesn't know you want to put the text and numbers together, since they are all individual strings, you need to combine the text and numbers together so Matlab knows to put them together, for example:

```
txt = {'Simulation parameters: ',['Number of loops = ',  num2str(loops_num)],['Number of subcarriers = ',num2str(Nfft)],['Number of frames = ',num2str(K)],['MT = ',num2str(MT)],['MR = ',num2str(MR)]};
text(4,0.5,txt,'FontSize',12)

str = {'Simulation parameters: ',['Number of loops = ',  num2str(loops_num)],...
                                 ['Number of subcarriers = ',num2str(Nfft)],...
                                 ['MT = ',num2str(MT)],...
                                 ['MR = ',num2str(MR)],...
                                 ['Number of frames = ',num2str(K)]};
annotation( 'textbox', 'String',str, 'Color', 'black', ...
            'FontSize', 14, 'Units', 'normalized', 'EdgeColor', 'none', ...
            'Position', [0.8,0.5,0.2,0] )
```

I combine the strings and variables using

```
[ 'text = ' num2str(value)];
```

You could also use

```
sprintf ( 'text = %f', value )
```

Its a bit more difficult to read, but its more powerful and a lot faster (for one off conversions this is irrelevant, but useful to know for future reference)

See [sprintf documentation for more info](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html)

Comment: If I remember, annotation uses figure co-ordinates so you would need to work them out yourself, so yes you can but not using the syntax you mentioned above

Comment: For future reference the above comment was answering a comment from the OP about could the annotation position be placed outside the axes using a similar position code to legends, e.g. `location, 'OutsideEast'`